# Wrangling Control of HTTP Headers in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http-headers

I'm working with ASP.NET MVC3, and I'm trying to get absolute control over my headers because a client application that I'm working with expects a very specific content type. What I'm finding when using Fiddler to examine the HTTP traffic is that the text encoding is being returned as part of the header.

For example, the client is expecting `application/appname` in the Content-Type header, but the server is returning `application/appname; charset=utf-8`. I think the client is using a strict comparison for checking the type, so I want to be able to specify exactly what is emitted in the headers.

Right now I have a custom ActionResult in which I clear the headers and then specify only the content type, but the encoding still seems to be added on.

How can I remove the encoding from the Content-Type header?

Comment: Can you convince them that charset is preferred ala http://www.w3.org/International/O-HTTP-charset.en.php#charset

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Charset Encoding in ASP.NET Response](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2007/Dec/23/Charset-Encoding-in-ASPNET-Response) from Rick Strahl is an older (2007) article, but maybe give it a try.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/appname";
Response.Charset = null;
```